# xpath запрос java

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Есть ли возможность с помощью xpath запроса вытащить 2 атрибута каждого элемента, которые удовлетворяют условиям запроса? Допустим id и value, грубо говоря получить массив, элементы которого массивы из двух значений. Если можно, то как?

Comment: Так java или python? В заголовке одно, в теге - другое. Впрочем, для xpath это не важно.

Comment: Используйте оператор `|` - `or`.

Comment: Уточните что вы хотите, поконкретнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @nick_gabpe я хочу получить атрибуты элементов.
у каждого элемента есть 2 атрибута 
одним запросом хочу получить значения этих атрибутов, таким образом, чтобы знать, кому принадлежит данный атрибут
получение самого элемента не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `|` - оператор объединения.

Например, имеется xml вида:

```
<nodes>
  <node id="1" value="foo" />
  <node id="2" value="bar" />
</nodes>
```

XPath для получения атрибутов `id` и `value` может выглядеть так:

```
"//node/@id | //node/@value"
```